# What is type: $Keys<User> in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I'm new to flow and react, redux-observable.

I was told to use type: `$Key<Users>`

What is `$Key<>?`

I know "type:" is Flow.

my code is below.

```
export const convertUsersToJapanese = (type: string): string => {
  switch (type) {
    case: 'name':
      return: '名前':
    default:
      return: 'その他':
  }
};
```

IS this right Answer?
switch(type: `$Keys<Clinic>`)

what is `$Keys<>`

Is there js ninja?

thanks.

Comment: Thats a union type of strings representing the keys of an object. And it seems like you should change the passed parameter `type: string` to `type: $Keys<User>`

Comment: thanks.however, there is no $ in flow's union type's page.

Comment: what is $？
I have no idea.

Comment: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/

Comment: oh , thanks Jonas W
(σ≧▽≦)σ really thanks